# GeoServer Web Map Service

Tags: geoserver

I have added all data in PostgreSQL with the help of PostGIS.  I made a store in GeoServer, but after adding data when I click on the OpenLayers option it does not open, and a file downloaded is shown at the bottom (showing WMS service).

What is the problem?

Comment: First of all question not clear. After created store in Geoserver with database, you need to publish the layers for each table in the stores or with SQL views. Then from layer preview page, you can open in openlayers and check it. You need to provide what is the exception, you are getting to help specifically. You could get help from geoserver-users mailing list too.

Comment: please post the exception (geoserver.log) if you want help to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If trying to view a layer on the openlayers preview results in an error it means the layer is miconfigured somehow. You should see an exception on the console or in the geoserver log. Impossible to know what the issue is without it.